# Rotate svg line with JavaScript (not CSS)

Tags: javascript, svg

I've got the following svg line:

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
    <line id="skyline" x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="50%" y2="90%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:10" />
</svg>
```

Trying to rotate the line multiple times seems to add many rotate(X) to the transform attribute, not simply overriding the value every time:

```
var skyline = document.getElementById("skyline");

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var rotation = skyline.getAttribute("transform") + i;
    skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + ")");
}
```

How can I properly get the rotate attribute, and how can I properly override in multiple times?

Comment: Why not use a CSS transition? Or a CSS animation? --- Just curious why you have just ruled it out.

Comment: CSS would be fine, as long as I can use javascript (not jQuery).

Comment: Of course. As jQuery uses native JS anyway. It's not hard to set CSS properties using JS.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the same attribute in synchronous loop doesn't make sense. If you want some sort of an animation you need to introduce time delay. The most straight forward way is to use `setTimeout`

```
var skyline = document.getElementById("skyline");

var angle = getOriginalAngle(),
    finalAngle = angle + 100;

function rotate() {
   skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (angle++) + "deg)");
   (angle < finalAngle) && setTimeout(rotate, 12); // repeat every 12 ms
}

rotate(); // launch animation
```

*UPD* Or if you want your changes to be in sync with browser rendering loop you can use `requestAnimationFrame`

```
function rotate() {
   skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (angle++) + "deg)");
   (angle < finalAngle) && requestAnimationFrame(rotate); // +- 60 fps
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `requestAnimationFrame(rotate)` instead of a timeout. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I'd too. But we are talking about the most straight forward way :)

Comment: I agree. I do personally argue that `requestAnimationFrame` is more straight forward.

Comment: I cannot assume the initial degree is 0, so I need to get the rotation degree at first.

Comment: @KasperNielsen How does it get initial rotation angle? Do you have control over this angle? If yes you can make this angle accessible from within rotate function. Otherwise you'll need to use some linear algebra as in answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your line doesn't already have a `transform`, you can just do:

```
var skyline = document.getElementById("skyline");

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ")");
}
```

But that doesn't work as is because you aren't giving the browser a chance to render the updated SVG.  Also it would run too fast even if it did update.

So you need to use an interval, timeout or `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```
var i = 0;

function rotate() {
  skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (i++) + ")");
  if (i < 100)
    setTimeout(rotate, 100);
}

setTimeout(rotate, 100);
```

If your elements could already have a transform, then you will need to get the current transform and manipulate it.  For example:

```
var i = 0;

function rotate() {
  var matrixList = skyline.transform.baseVal;
  if (matrixList.length === 0) {
    skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (i++) + ")");
  } else {
    var firstTransform = matrixList.getItem(0);
    firstTransform.setMatrix(firstTransform.matrix.rotate(1));
    i++;
  }
  if (i < 100)
    setTimeout(rotate, 100);
}

setTimeout(rotate, 100);
```

```js
var skyline = document.getElementById("skyline");
var i = 0;

function rotate() {
  var matrixList = skyline.transform.baseVal;
  if (matrixList.length === 0) {
    skyline.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (i++) + ")");
  } else {
    var firstTransform = matrixList.getItem(0);
    firstTransform.setMatrix(firstTransform.matrix.rotate(1));
    i++;
  }
  if (i < 100)
    setTimeout(rotate, 100);
}

setTimeout(rotate, 100);
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
    <line id="skyline" x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="50%" y2="90%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:10" transform="rotate(-10)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why use a for loop? Will this animate it? If so, how can the length of the animation be controlled?

Comment: And I do need to get the rotation degree at first... Cannot assume it's 0. But     var rotation = skyline.getAttribute("transform") doesn't work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I accidentally submitted my answer before getting to the bit where I explained why the first step wouldn't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Greensock is a great extension for CSS and JS which allows you to manipulate SVG's based on id's or classnames of the element in question:

[GreenSock](http://greensock.com/)

Here's an example:

```js
TweenMax.staggerTo('.skyline', 2, {rotation: -90, repeat:-1, yoyo:true});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <line class="skyline" x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="50%" y2="90%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:10" />
</svg>
```

The best part is it will run in IE as well as being simple, easy to implement and easy to understand and well documented! It can be set to run automatically on page load, or when an event is fired such as a hover etc etc. you can choose whether it runs indefinitely or how many times you want it to run, and if you want it to have a yoyo effect or not (animation to run back and forth)

Comment: Also check out their ease settings, they're great and add extra "umph!" to your animations [easing with greensock](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/)

Answer (score 0):

Using: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

```js
function getRotate(el) {
  var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
  var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
    "fail...";

  var values = tr.split('(')[1];
  values = values.split(')')[0];
  values = values.split(',');
  var a = values[0];
  var b = values[1];
  var c = values[2];
  var d = values[3];

  var scale = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);


  // arc sin, convert from radians to degrees, round
  var sin = b / scale;
  // next line works for 30deg but not 130deg (returns 50);
  // var angle = Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI));
  var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));

  return angle
}

setInterval(rotate, 100);

function rotate() {
  var rotation = getRotate(document.getElementById("skyline")) + 5;

  console.log(rotation);

  skyline.setAttribute("style", "stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2;transform: rotate(" + rotation + "deg);transform-origin: center");
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <line id="skyline" x1="80" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2;transform: rotate(30deg);transform-origin: center" />
</svg>
```

Comment: i added transform origin to better demonstrate the situation